# How to enable client isolation in wpa_supplicant?

Tags: wpa-supplicant, hostapd

Is that possible to enable client isolation in `wpa_supplicant` when it's used as AP?

There is a configuration in `hostapd` called  `ap_isolate=1` . Is there a similar option in `wpa_supplicant`? 
thanks